# Where is the Android jar library?

Tags: android, command-line

As an academic exercise, I'm following [this](https://asantoso.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/how-to-build-android-application-package-apk-from-the-command-line-using-the-sdk-tools-continuously-integrated-using-cruisecontrol/) to build an Android app from the command line using just the android sdk.

I was wondering where in the Android SDK I could find the Android library to javac against? Otherwise, javac doesn't know where to find, for instance, `android.app.Activity`. I think dx needs the library too right?

Comment: people usually use gradle to build android apps, not javac directly. Anyway, your android.jar is located in the target sdk you are building against.

Comment: @njzk2 I looked at the docs on the Android page for creating a project through cli, but it would generate an Ant project? I find this tutorial, before I found one that would could generate a gradle from the command line.

Comment: @njzk2 Also, thank you, I found it. In retrospect it seems like it's a place I could've guessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As an academic exercise, I'm following this to build an Android app from the command line using just the android sdk.

That blog post is from 2009. At the time of this writing, it is 2015. The build process has substantially changed since 2009.

> I was wondering where in the Android SDK I could find the Android library to javac against?

`$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/platform-NNN`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you have the Android SDK installed and `NNN` is an API level (e.g., 21). In there, you will find an `android.jar` file that contains the mocks of the Android SDK API that we compile against.

> I looked at the docs on the Android page for creating a project through cli, but it would generate an Ant project?

I have heard that you can have a `-g` switch to generate Gradle build files instead of Ant, but I haven't ever used it. Personally, I would just copy the Gradle build files from a known-working project and modify them to suit.

Comment: Your comment about 2009 vs 2015 is duly noted.
I'll also check out that `-g` switch.
And thank you for the great answer! I'll accept it as soon as stackoverflow will let me accept it.